# Property/Synthesize errors

Tags: objective-c, properties

Sorry to keep asking basic questions here but I don't know where else to go. Wrote some code with a slider, textfield and buttons for incrementing the slider to demonstrate key value coding. Everything worked find. The next step was to use 'property' and 'synthesize' in place of the accessor and setter methods;

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
@interface KVCController : NSObject  {
    int fido;
}
@property(readwrite, assign) int fido;
@end
```

~~~~~

```
@implementation KVCController
@synthesize fido;

- (id)init{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code here.
        [self setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:5] forKey:@"fido"];
        NSNumber *n = [self valueForKey:@"fido"];
        NSLog(@"fido = %@", n);
    }

    return self;
}
~~~~~~~
@end
```

I get an incomplete implementation error on  @implementation KVCController. If I put the get and set methods for 'fido' in it clears up.
The second error occurs with  @synthesize fido;. It says property must be declared in the implementation. Everything is copied correctly out of the book and near as I can tell, it looks just like all the other uses of property and synthesize I have looked at. Anyone have any ideas on what I am missing or doing wrong?

Xcode 4.1 automatically creates a delegate class which I usually ignore if I am not working on delegates. I created my own class for the KVC exercise and just added the property/synthesize declarations to it with appropriate modifications and got the errors. I just put the property/synthesize declarations into the delegate class, moved my IBAction code to the appropriate places, redid the bindings, and erased the class I created and everything worked fine. Do property/synthesize declarations need to be treated like delegate material?

Comment: Also - you've declared `fido` to be an `int` but you are initialising it with an `NSNumber`. All you need to do is write `fido = 5;`

Comment: The author said the key value coding only works on objects so I left it the way it was. Taking it out and putting in fido = 5 does not make any difference (still the same errors). I thought you needed the KVC for the property/synthesize declarations.

Comment: You can only use KVC to set properties of objects. That doesn't mean that the properties themselves need to be objects.

Comment: Sometimes - just doing a clean build clears up spurious errors

Comment: -Since it's just an example project from a book - put it up somewhere where I can download it and I'll have a look for you.

Answer (score 2):

**incomplete implementation** means you have a `-(void)something` that may be defined in your header that you are not using in your `@implementation`. Make sure that you do not have any unused methods listed in your header. if you do, either remove them from the header, or create the method in your implementation.

```
- (void) dosomething
{
    /* blank for now */
}
```

if you have `-(void)dosomething` in your implementation, define it in your header.

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
@interface KVCController : NSObject  {
    int fido;
}
@property(readwrite, assign) int fido;
- (void) dosomething;
@end
```

Comment: In the first part of the exercise, the author was doing a long winded way of implementing key value coding and I had it working. When he switched to property/synthesize, I just commented out all the -(int)fido, -(void)setFido and (IBAction)methods so there is nothing extra in the header, just what I wrote.